# VB 2010 - How to read an INI file that is on the internet without downloading it

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, ini

I need to know how can I read an INI file that is on the internet without download it into the computer, can save it into memory, I need to do this with Visual Basic 2010.

I need to read all content and get every value from every section but without download the file, I've tried with this class:

[Question: Read and write in INI file](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/45603-read-write-ini-file.html)

But only works with computer-stored-files, not with files on internet, I've been thinking in get all content of the INI file and save it into a string, but the class doesn't read it at all, can anyone help me? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you mean  "without downloading it"? To access a file on the internet, you *have* to download it. You can keep it in memory to not save it, but it still gets downloaded.

Comment: Yes, you are right, what I mean, is not save the file on computer, can keep it on memory, but I can't save it as "file", I edited question for more clarity, thanks

Comment: That class uses the GetPrivateProfileString API which requires a physical file, period. If you don't want to download, save, read then delete you will need to find or write an alternate INI file parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, the easiest way is to download the file to a temp location. Use [CreateTempFile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195763) to get a temp file name.

If you can't save the file at all, you can download it to memory with the following (untested):

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse

request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url)  ' url of the file
request.Method = "GET"
response = request.GetResponse()


Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default)
    Dim fileStr As String = reader.ReadToEnd()  ' fileStr contains the contents of the file
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I changed the class for parse INI, but this code worked perfect for download it into the memory.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is reading the file as a webpage (basically, this is what it is) and then parsing all the information you get. I have used the code below many times and works pretty well:

```
Public Class Form1
    Friend WithEvents webBrower0 As New WebBrowser
    Friend WithEvents tabs As New TabControl
    Friend WithEvents tabPage0 As New TabPage

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        startBrowser()
    End Sub
    Public Sub startBrowser()

        Dim url As String = "http://..."

        tabs.Controls.Add(tabPage0)
        tabPage0.Controls.Add(webBrower0)
        AddHandler webBrower0.Navigating, AddressOf WebBrowser_Navigating
        AddHandler webBrower0.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted
        tabPage0.Refresh()

        webBrower0.Navigate(url)

    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs)
    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim source_string As String = webBrower0.DocumentText 'content of the file
    End Sub
End Class
```

After reading everything, the string `source_string` will be populated with the file content. It follows the html format but you shouldn't find any problem to extract the information you want.